# UIButton not showing in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem, displayobject

Following is a code to display a button to the toolbar.

```
UIButton myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];

[myButton setBackgroundImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *myToolbarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
```

Nothing gets displayed on the toolbar. Please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: maybe its becz you havent set the frame for the button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[myToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myToolbarButton]]; // might help
```

OR if it's a navigation bar

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myToolbarButton;
```

Also you should set the frame for the custom button, something like this:

```
UIButton *mybutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:0,0,200,50];
```

Then if you want to add a selector/callback:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I have done that. I'm just modifying a UIBarButtonItem to having a custom view so adding it to the buttons array and then adding setting the toolbar to it is all done.

Comment: how do  you set the frame? I've looked and can't find a suitable method.

Comment: `UIButton *mybutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:0,0,200,50];`

Comment: When I initialize my UIBarButtonItem with a custom view(UIButton), how do I register the function callback? because there is no method that enables us to do that i.e. there is no selector parameter.

Comment: thank you. when i initialize the UIBarButtonItem with a custom view(UIButton) on the toolbar, i want to set the uibarbuttonitemstyle to uibarbuttomitemstyleplain so that it glows when it is clicked. How do i do this? because setting the style option is provided in initWithImage.

Comment: No I'm afraid you haven't got my question. I want to use the UIBarButtonItem(which is different from the UIButton). Now the UIbarButtonItemStyle is available for UIBarButtonItem. So I initialize my UIBarButton item to my UIButton(so that with UIButton, I can resize the image) and then I say UIBarButtonIteminstance.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain. But when I tap it, it does NOT glow. But according to the documentation of that style, it should.

Comment: @Namratha let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2613/discussion-between-alex-coplan-and-namratha)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myButtonItem; // and change for the right button.
```

Where self is a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add this button to the toolbar!

```
NSArray *toolbarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myToolbarButton,nil]; // you can more buttons here
[aToolbar setItems:toolbarItems animated:NO]; // change to YES if you want to have nice animation
[toolbarItems release];
```

If you want to add a button to navigation bar, use this:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myToolbarButton]; // or setLeft...
```

Also, you should remember to set the frame of `myButton`:

```
[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 32)];
```